# Opencart Seo Url Issue

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, url-routing, opencart2.3

I have been working on the SEO URL an opencart. I used an extension (SEO Keyword Lite) for managing the SEO URL an opencart 2.3.0.2. The problem is when I add SEO URL for any product or category up to 1 segment i.e.  **`http://baseurl/product-name`** it works fine but when I add SEO URL up to 2 segments i.e. **`http://baseurl/product/product-name`** it shows an error that "The page requested can not be found!"

**My Seo Url File:**

```
class ControllerStartupSeoUrl extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Add rewrite to url class
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $this->url->addRewrite($this);
        }

        // Decode URL
        if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
            $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);

            // remove any empty arrays from trailing
            if (utf8_strlen(end($parts)) == 0) {
                array_pop($parts);
            }

            foreach ($parts as $part) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

                    if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
                        $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
                        if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                            $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
                        } else {
                            $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
                        }
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
                        $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
                        $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($query->row['query'] && $url[0] != 'information_id' && $url[0] != 'manufacturer_id' && $url[0] != 'category_id' && $url[0] != 'product_id') {
                        $this->request->get['route'] = $query->row['query'];
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
                if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function rewrite($link) {
        $url_info = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));

        $url = '';

        $data = array();

        parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($data['route'])) {
                if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        unset($data[$key]);
                    }
                } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                    $categories = explode('_', $value);

                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                        if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                            $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                        } else {
                            $url = '';

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    unset($data[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($url) {
            unset($data['route']);

            $query = '';

            if ($data) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $query .= '&' . rawurlencode((string)$key) . '=' . rawurlencode((is_array($value) ? http_build_query($value) : (string)$value));
                }

                if ($query) {
                    $query = '?' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', trim($query, '&'));
                }
            }

            return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
        } else {
            return $link;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried **print_r()** on every step and tried my solutions but it shows the same request not found.
what I understand is that the seo url is hitting accordingly but it fails to find the resources related to the url and it shows "request not found". I am new to open cart, I would appreciate if anyone guide me through this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer for setting SEO URL, just put some line of code in rewrite function:

```
public function rewrite($link) {
        $url_info = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));

        $url = '';

        $data = array();

        parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);

            if ($data['route'] == 'common/home'){
                $url .= '/';
            }
            if ($data['route'] == 'information/contact'){
                $url .= '/contact';
            }
            if ($data['route'] == 'account/return/add'){
                $url .= '/returnadd';
            }
            if ($data['route'] == 'information/sitemap'){
                $url .= '/sitemap';
            }
            if ($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer'){
                $url .= '/manufacturer';
            }
            if ($data['route'] == 'account/voucher'){
                $url .= '/voucher';
            }
            if ($data['route'] == 'affiliate/login'){
                $url .= '/affiliatelogin';
            }
            if ($data['route'] == 'product/special'){
                $url .= '/special';
            }
                    if ($data['route'] == 'product/product'){
                $url .= '/product';
            }

                        if ($data['route'] == 'product/category'){
                $url .= '/category';
            }
            if ($data['route'] == 'account/login'){
                $url .= '/login';
            }
            if ($data['route'] == 'checkout/cart'){
                $url .= '/cart';
            }

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($data['route'])) {
                if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        unset($data[$key]);
                    }
                } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                    $categories = explode('_', $value);

                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                        if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                            $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                        } else {
                            $url = '';

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    unset($data[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($url) {
            unset($data['route']);

            $query = '';

            if ($data) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $query .= '&' . rawurlencode((string)$key) . '=' . rawurlencode((is_array($value) ? http_build_query($value) : (string)$value));
                }

                if ($query) {
                    $query = '?' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', trim($query, '&'));
                }
            }

            return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
        } else {
            return $link;
        }
    }
```

and most important mention these keywords in **oc_url_alias** like:

```
query= product/category   keyword=category
```

I hope this will help to many of people facing problem regarding seo url.

Thanks.